# How can i avoid update a password in Laravel when the password input field is left empty?

Tags: php, laravel

I got this code in laravel that allows an administrator to update an user's password:

```
public function editarmembro(Request $dados)    {

        $validatedData = $dados->validate([

            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'credencial' => 'required',

        ]);

        $dados = $dados->all();

        if (!empty($dados['password'])) {
            $dados['password'] = Hash::make($dados['password']);
        }

        DB::table('users')->where('id', $dados['id'])->update(
            [ 'name' => $dados['name'], 'email' => $dados['email'], 'credencial' => $dados['credencial'], 'password' => $dados['password'], 'sobre' => $dados['sobre'], 'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),  ]
        );

        return redirect()->route('membros')->with('mensagemSucesso',  'As informações do membro "'.$dados['name'].'" foram atualizadas com sucesso.');

    }
```

My problem is, if he left the password field blank, i get an error screen saying that the password field cannot be NULL. I want my code to NOT update the password if he left the password field blank, but DO update if he inserts something in password field.

Help, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it from the `$dados` array if it's empty:

```
if (!empty($dados['password'])) 
    $dados['password'] = Hash::make($dados['password']);
else 
    unset($dados['password']);
```

or with ternary operator

```
!empty($dados['password'])? $dados['password'] = Hash::make($dados['password']): unset($dados['password']);
```

and since all the names of the fields match those of the request and the `updated_at` field should auto-complete, you don't need to reassemble the array for the update.

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $dados['id'])->update($dados);
```

---

If you want to reassemble the array anyway, you can do so

```
$update_dados = [ 
        'name' => $dados['name'], 
        'email' => $dados['email'], 
        'credencial' => $dados['credencial'], 
        'sobre' => $dados['sobre'], 
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),  
];

if (!empty($dados['password'])) 
    $update_dados['password'] = Hash::make($dados['password']);

DB::table('users')->where('id', $dados['id'])->update($update_dados);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to merge to the array with all the values (except the password) the password only if exists / is set:

```
    $your_array = [ 
        'name' => $dados['name'], 
        'email' => $dados['email'], 
        'credencial' => $dados['credencial'], 
        'sobre' => $dados['sobre'], 
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),  
    ];
    DB::table('users')->where('id', $dados['id'])->update(
        empty($dados['password']) ? $your_array : array_merge($your_array, ['password' => $dados['password']])
    );
```